# Selenium open chrome default profile but get an error WebDriverException

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to open chrome with default browser by Selenium. Once the chrome is opened, the cell output shows an error:

```
"WebDriverException"
"Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited normally.\n  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)\n  (The process started from chrome location C:\\\\Program Files\\\\Google\\\\Chrome\\\\Application\\\\chrome.exe is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)\nStacktrace:\nBacktrace:\n\t(No symbol) [0x00B0F243]\n\t(No symbol) [0x00A97FD1]\n\t(No symbol) [0x0098D04D]\n\t(No symbol) [0x009AC24E]\n\t(No symbol) [0x009A82E9]\n\t(No symbol) [0x009DF056]\n\t(No symbol) [0x009DEB2A]\n\t(No symbol) [0x009D8386]\n\t(No symbol) [0x009B163C]\n\t(No symbol) [0x009B269D]\n\tGetHandleVerifier [0x00DA9A22+2655074]\n\tGetHandleVerifier [0x00D9CA24+2601828]\n\tGetHandleVerifier [0x00BB8C0A+619850]\n\tGetHandleVerifier [0x00BB7830+614768]\n\t(No symbol) [0x00AA05FC]\n\t(No symbol) [0x00AA5968]\n\t(No symbol) [0x00AA5A55]\n\t(No symbol) [0x00AB051B]\n\tBaseThreadInitThunk [0x7579FEF9+25]\n\tRtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77297BBE+286]\n\tRtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77297B8E+238]\n"
```

I also run without profile argument, it works fine. But when profile argument is added, the error occurs.

Chrome version: 108.0.5359.125
Python version: 3.9.12
Selenium version: 4.7.2
Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

chrome_options = Options()

chrome_options.add_argument("--user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\Rattapong.Pojpatin\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\") # change to profile path
chrome_options.add_argument('--profile-directory=Profile 2')

browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="D:\\Chromedriver\\chromedriver.exe", chrome_options=chrome_options)
browser.get('https://sellercenter.lazada.co.th/apps/seller/login')
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Close all the chrome browser windows and 'chromedriver.exe' then execute the code.